# Using array value as an array name

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am using 5 arrays and 2 FOR loops to create a set of divs on a page, but the inner loop is not working properly and is returning UNDEFINED for some items. I know the reason for this is because because it is using the length of the actual colour name [red(3),orange(6), green(5), blue(4)] instead of the actual length of those arrays.

How do use the actual colour name from the first array (colours) dynamically with the second array name. What am I missing please???

```
var colours = ["red", "orange", "green", "blue"];
var red = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"];
var orange = ["item5", "item6"];
var green = ["item7", "item8", "item9", "item10", "item11"];
var blue = ["item12"];
//generate coloured boxes
for (var i = 0; i < colours.length; i++) {
    var colour = colours[i];
    $("<div class='box " + colour + "' id='" + colour + "'>").appendTo('#boxes');
    //generate items in boxes
    for (var j = 0; j < colours[i].length; j++) {
        $("<div id='" + red[j] + "'>" + red[j] + "</div>").appendTo("#" + colours[i]);
    }
    $("</div>").appendTo('#boxes');
}
```

Comment: Apologies I made a copy and paste mistake. Correct problem code below;

`$("<div id='item" + j + "'>" + colours[i[j]] + "</div>").appendTo("#" + colours[i]);`

Comment: You can edit your question to update the code using the `edit` link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is bad programming; you might need end up using `eval`:

```
var colours = ["red", "orange", "green", "blue"];
var red = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"];
var orange = ["item5", "item6"];
var green = ["item7", "item8", "item9", "item10", "item11"];
var blue = ["item12"];
```

It would be better if you create a dictionary of color names and their items (and use jQuery functions to create elements):

```
var colours = ["red", "orange", "green", "blue"];
var colourValues = {
    red: ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"],
    orange: ["item5", "item6"],
    green: ["item7", "item8", "item9", "item10", "item11"],
    blue: ["item12"]
};
for (var i = 0; i < colours.length; i++) {
    var colour = colours[i];
    var colourValue = colourValues[colour];
    var $box = $("<div></div>", { "class": "box " + colour, id: colour }).appendTo("#boxes");
    for (var j = 0; j < colourValue.length; j++) {
        $("<div></div>", { id: colourValue[j] }).text(colourValue[j]).appendTo($box);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't say it's bad as you don't provisionally know why there were separate arrays - maybe there was a reason originally?!

The dictionary way is much CLEANER though. Thanks for highlighting this.

Comment: @SimonGoldsmith if you must use separate arrays you can still use dictionary: `var colourValues = {red: red, orange: orange...}`.